# Como criar uma enum a partir de uma string em Dart?

Tags: dart, enums

Digamos que eu esteja construindo objetos a partir de entradas no banco de dados. O banco guarda, por exemplo, a espécie do animal de estimação que uma pessoa tem. No banco, estas informações podem ser guardadas como `cat`, `dog`, `bird`. Por isso, em Dart, eu criaria a enum:

```
enum Pet {
    cat,
    dog,
    bird
}
```

Mas não há um jeito óbvio de converter a string que vem do banco de dados para uma enum. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há dois jeitos bons de se fazer isso. O primeiro é criar uma extensão para a enum. Ele ocupa mais linhas e é mais demorado de fazer, mas a vantagem é que dá para aproveitar a estrutura para fazer várias outras coisas.

```
enum Pet {
    cat,
    dog,
    bird
}

extension PetMethods on Pet {
  static Pet createFromString(String s) {
    final pet = {
      'cat': Pet.cat,
      'dog': Pet.dog,
      'bird': Pet.bird
    }[s];

    if (pet == null) { throw 'Invalid string value provided'; }
    return pet;
  }
}
```

Agora, na hora de criar o `Pet`, eu simplesmente usaria `PetMethods.createFromString('cat');`. Dá para usar a extensão para definir todo tipo de método relacionado àquela enum.

---

O outro jeito é mais enxuto, talvez valha mais a pena se sua enum não tiver que ter mais funções:

```
final pet = Pet.values.byName('cat'); // retorna Pet.cat
```

Ou ainda:

```
final pet = Pet.values.asNameMap()['cat']; // mesmo efeito
```

Comment: Seria legal falar a diferença ou vantagem de usar cada forma, ou o porquê de existir mais de uma forma.

Comment: As vantagens eu citei acima: uma é bem mais compacta e a outra te dá mais possibilidades. Usando o primeiro jeito você pode, por exemplo, emitir um warning caso uma das variantes sendo usada esteja depreciada (quando você estiver mantendo uma biblioteca). O motivo de ser possível fazer dos dois jeitos é que a `extension` na verdade é um conjunto de métodos e operadores que pode ser aplicado a qualquer tipo de dados (inclusive tipos vindos de pacotes), não somente às `Enum`s.